# Plugging in the ebook reader app of choice

Tags: ebook-reader, ebooks

In Android you can choose which keyboard to plug in for input.

So why can't I choose which ebook reader I want to plug in to read digital books, such as the ones that you can view, even after purchasing them, on Google Play Books, or the ones that can be viewed in O'Reilly Media subscriptions, where programming books can be found.

Is what I want even feasible?

Why hasn't it been done?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question. You have dozen of ebook reader apps, those who use open formats (epub, ...), unbound to specific ebook stores and reader apps that are bound to a certain store (like Amazon Kindle app). It is a decision of the ebook store operator which reader apps are allowed to access their ebooks and which not. If you don't like ebooks that are bound to a certain app, don't use the store. There are a lot of alternatives.